# Why is banner image in a simple HTML site different sizes of different pages?

Tags: html, ios, css, image-size

This simple HTML site of 9 pages has been used as a template over the years for multiple sites.  It was not built for that purpose but that's what I am dealing with.  The entire site needs an overhaul, is not responsive, etc. etc.. If you look closely at the code there are multiple contradictions in width properties for the page and banner image.  There is a long to term plan to build a new one.  In the short term it is presenting me with an irritating quirk that I have been unable to solve.

The banner image displays as desired on desktop sites and androids.  On an iPhone and iPad the banner displays as desired on 7 of the 9 pages.  On two of the pages the image extends beyond edge of the screen. The same rules are applied to each image on the various pages and the HTML appears to be identical. The photos are all identical sizes and resolutions.

Why would two pages be different?  I know there are errors in the code but wouldn't the same errors apply to each image?  I don't see anything in the code that would affect one page differently from any other.

I have tried all variations of width, max-width, auto, percent size, pixel size, and view screen size.  None have created uniformity.  The image on the first two pages is always different than the following 7 pages. I have also run the code through validators and each page has exactly the same errors on them none of which relate to image size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/oneclub_17.dwt"       codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/doa5ucf.js"></script>
<script>try[{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <script     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>BOKF ONE Club 2017-Welcome</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <!-- InstanceParam name="Banner Image" type="URL" value="Images/banner_bokf_hmb17_welcome.jpg" -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">

        <div id="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-content">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">WELCOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="destination.html">DESTINATION</a></li>
                            <li><a href="hotel.html">HOTEL</a></li>
                             <li><a href="agenda.html">AGENDA</a></li>
                           <li><a href="activities.html">ACTIVITIES</a></li>
                           <li><a href="climate.html">CLIMATE</a></li>
                           <li><a href="questions.html">Q&amp;A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                            <li><a href="register.html">REGISTER</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-container">
        <img src="Images/banner_bokf_hmb17_welcome.jpg" width="1460">       </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="photo-caption"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Caption" -->Ritz-Carlton Half Moon Bay<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
      <div id="main-container">
        <div id="content"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Body" -->
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Only 30 minutes south of San Francisco is a dramatic stretch of California coastline. Here, craggy and windswept bluffs tumble onto shores pounded by endless surf to postcard-worthy perfection. This is Half Moon Bay where we will celebrate our elite’s 2016 achievements as ONE Club, March 30–April 2, 2017.</p>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
      </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Wyndham Jade, LLC. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>

    </div>
<script defer src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
.container{
width: 1280px;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 25px;
}
#header{
background-color: white;
height: auto;
}
#header-top{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
z-index: 2;
}
    #header-top .container{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .header-content{
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size:12px;
    }


#nav {
position: relative;
height: 50px;
background-image: url(../Images/oneclub_weblogo_2017.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left center;
padding-top: 0px;
}
#nav ul {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
line-height: 12px;
margin-top: 27px;
}
#nav li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}


#home-banner {
text-align: center;
}

.banner-container{
height: 480px;
margin-top: 50px;
position: relative;
background-color: #FFF;
}
.banner-container img {
display: block;
width: 1460px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
height: 480px;
}
.banner-container img land {
display: block;
width: 1460px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
height: 480px;
}

#main-container {
width: 1280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help being able to see a comparison of two pages that are displaying differently in a bin or fiddle.

A few things I noticed in the code and CSS example that might be disrupting width.

1. Nested elements with fixed widths
2. Padding set on nested fixed width elements while using display:block
3. Links in the header were overflowing to the right, causing horizontal scroll

To help you get more consistent results try using variable widths and use the max-width style property. When including padding in fixed width elements, use [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to avoid unwanted horizontal scroll issues. Box sizing might solve your issue directly.

[Here is a jsbin with close to your original markup and CSS](http://jsbin.com/rotawo)

[Same page with variable width (width: 100%) and max-width set.](http://jsbin.com/puhuwi)
Also removed padding left/right on a couple of the nested elements, and reduced the width on the header container to prevent overflow.

```css
#header-top {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 98%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of things. First, you should remove the width constraint on the `<img src="Images/banner_bokf_hmb17_welcome.jpg" width="1460">`, since it's being handled in CSS. Also, in the CSS, `.banner-container img land` isn't defined anywhere and could be causing an error that you won't see.

Have you also tried using the Developer options available to you in any browser (activated using F12). Also, for the pages that don't work, there may be an old cached CSS file that's mucking up the results. You'll also want to [clear the cached data for the pages giving you trouble](http://www.imore.com/how-clear-stored-website-data-ios-7-safari) on iOS. This should do a fresh fetch on the latest CSS values and hopefully display the right way.

I do, however, appreciate that 7 of 9 pages work #startrek

As far as future work is involved... I'd suggest using [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) or [something similar](http://modernweb.com/2014/02/17/8-bootstrap-alternatives/)...

Comment: Yes,I have used the developer tools. F12 is a girl's best friend. I have tried removing the inline width constraint and removing the "land" rule as well as creating every other possible permutation of width rules. None have created uniformity in the images.

I know how to build a responsive site.  My experience is that using bootstrap etc. adds nothing that I can't already do with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Granted, and I agree that those kinds of tools can sometimes remove the control and even ease of use. Just offering based on my experience. The only thing else that can think of (since the HTML and CSS is simple) is that somehow the browser is messing up the image size itself. Mozilla offers the ability to "measure" your image and you can even look at the raw image resource and see what size it is being interpreted as. Not sure what else it could be unless the wrapper divs are somehow forcing the image size down. They shouldn't be though, as seen by the almost total uniformity